# What's my mistake when I am trying to work with files in C?

Tags: c, xcode, file

I am a beginner in programming and I need to find out palindromes in the first file and put them into the second one.
I have a Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x68), when I am trying to start the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 int main ()
 {
     char line[255];
     unsigned long k;
     int i;
     int flag = 1;
     FILE *file = fopen("1zad.txt", "r");
     FILE *new = fopen("new1.txt", "a");
     while(!feof(file) && !ferror(file))
     {
         fgets(line, 255, file);
         k = strlen(line);
         for (i = 0;i < k/2;i++)
         {
             if(line[i]!=line[k-1-i]){
                 flag = 0;
             }
         }
         if(flag == 1){
             fputs(line, new);
         }
     }
     fclose(file);
     fclose(new);
     return 0;
 }
```

it underlines "!feof", text files are available and near the program file.
i have no ideas what is going wrong

Comment: You are reading 255 bytes from a file and calling it "like" but it's not a line. It's 255 bytes. It won't have a length. Did you mean to read one line from the file?

Comment: I need to read some lines from the file

Comment: Then read lines, not entire 255 byte chunks. Make sure to leave space for the 0 string terminator

Comment: See also [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941)

Comment: ok, I will check it